# Distribution of $(X,Y)$ when $(X,Y)$ is randomly selected inside a triangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The task says:

> A dot is randomly selected inside triangle $\{(x, y) : x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 1\}$; $(X , Y)$ are coordinates to this dot. Determine the distribution function and density of that vector.

This is sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nph8.jpg

And this is the solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNlNV.jpg

I don't understand the solution to this random vector problem.

I understand that is F(x , y) which is probability P(X < x, Y < y) for f(x, y) when x <= 0 or y <= 0  =  0. I also understand that F(x, y) ) = 1 when x >= 1 and  y >= 1 = 1. But I don't understand any of the other solutions so any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Comment: Consider all the possible cases as in the solution :-) to provide the joint density ... it is tedious but a good exercise!